# visual studio code at remote machine .vscode file (linux)

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

i have vscode on my windows and connecting to the linux machine via ssh extensions.
the problem : the vnc(linux machine) i have is limited with space (~100Mb) and when connected via ssh the vcode is generating .vscode directory that weight more than the free space i have.
my question : how can i change the path of the generated .vscode directory ?

tried to look in the settings but that didn't helped

Comment: Please update to be more precise:  (1) What do you do on which machine? (2) What are theses "ssh extensions"? // As VNC and (plain) SSH as well make you work directly at the remote machine, the remote machine has to fit the requirements, the local one is has only the minimal requirements for a terminal. — Or the extension of ssh does some magic, that we need to understand first.